# Django admin like functionality in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp, django-admin

I am a seasoned Django user and can't live without its admin module. Is there anything equivalent in PHP, preferably but not limited to using CakePHP?

Comment: Whats your goal? It does not make much sense to build a separate admin interface outside of the CakePHP app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii Framework

http://www.yiiframework.com/

[Here's a tour so you can see how its Gii feature works.](http://www.yiiframework.com/tour/) Gii is a web interface that generates files, bypassing the need for a command line.

Comment: Whats the point in posting advertising for another framework (that is IMO not as good as cake) when the question is explicitly about CakePHP and on top of that does not even match what he asked for in the other framework?

Comment: no I think this is a reasonable attempt at a decent answer, I just mentioned Cakephp as a preference but could well tolerate something else if the desired functionality is there even in part.

Comment: @user698585 said in their question... "Is there anything equivalent in php, **preferably but not limited to** using cakephp."