# Mimic Django's "add" button for related fields in admin

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Django has this admin feature for related fields when you press the "+" button, and you can add new data and then it attaches via jQuery, I'm assuming. I've looked at the code, and I could not find it anywhere.

How would I mimic this in PHP?

[image]

So, once you add the new 'Category', the ID attaches onto the 'Category' field in the window behind it. Then you submit the form and wala. How does this work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django admin like functionality in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118656/django-admin-like-functionality-in-php)

Comment: @Yogesh: Not really: that talks about the _whole_ of the django admin: this is just asking about one small feature.

Comment: Matthew is correct. I'm asking about a very specific feature from the Django admin, not the entire admin itself. So now no one is going to answer my question because it got flagged as a duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice feature of Django Admin, that even SonataAdminBundle for Symfony didn't implement (yet).
I browsed the source code and found this JavaScript function:

**django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js**

```
function showAddAnotherPopup(triggeringLink) {
    var name = triggeringLink.id.replace(/^add_/, '');
    name = id_to_windowname(name);
    href = triggeringLink.href
    if (href.indexOf('?') == -1) {
        href += '?_popup=1';
    } else {
        href  += '&_popup=1';
    }
    var win = window.open(href, name, 'height=500,width=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
    win.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Maybe you can take this function and implement your own logic in PHP. When clicking on the '+' sign the function is called like this:

`<a href="/admin/`*app*`/`*model*`/add/" class="add-another" id="add_id_tags" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);">`

The function call is made in an old fashioned way with no use of jQuery.

I'm sorry I can't help you further.

Comment: The magic is inside the popup. When you submit the form that's inside the popup, it'll submit the form via AJAX. When that request's finished, JS in the popup will update the parent window's DOM. For more information, read the docs on `window.opener`.